# How can I output a syscall’s name according to the number in the file unistd_64.h or unistd_32.h?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls, unistd.h

for example there are some macros in the unistd_64.h

```
...

#define __NR_semget 64

#define __NR_semop 65

#define __NR_semctl 66

#define __NR_shmdt 67

#define __NR_msgget 68

#define __NR_msgsnd 69

...
```

when I input a number

**64**

, it will output

**__NR_semget or semget**

c/cpp source code is much better,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syscall name and number mapping is largly dependent on the arch you are using.

[ausyscall](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/ausyscall.8.html) - provides mapping given the syscall number. Maybe you could do something like:

```
system("ausyscall 64 x86_64")
```

This should return **semget**

Comment: It works,and @n3rd4n1 his way works too,thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do that is by defining an array of strings representing the name of those definitions. There's no shortcut, unfortunately...

```
const char *name[] = {

    ...,

    /* this is now the 64th string... */
    "__NR_semget",
    "__NR_semop",

    ...
};

printf("name: %s\n", name[64]);
```

Comment: I've considered your way before,as you said "There's no shortcut",it's not so good,but it works actually,thanks for your answer.

Comment: [https://github.com/linnv/OpenDemo/blob/master/syscall_array/disabled_syscall_x64.h] just like line 347th.